# Tikz how to draw a conditional iterative statement

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw the figure below with Tikz.
[image: While statement]

So far, my code looks like this :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    % styles
    \tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered,draw=StanfordRed, fill=StanfordRed!20]
    \tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=defaultColor, fill=defaultColor!20]
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=StandfordBlue, fill=StandfordBlue!20, text width=4cm]
    \tikzstyle{normal} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=black!10, text width=4cm]
    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
    \tikzstyle{arrow_red} = [thick,->,>=stealth,draw=StanfordRed]

   % noeuds
   \node (start) [startstop] {Début};
   \node (ins_before) [normal, below of=start] {Instructions avant la structure itérative conditionnelle};
   \node (init) [process, below of=ins_before] {Instruction d'initialisation du compteur};
   \node (test) [decision, below of=init] {Test};
   \node (bloc) [process, below of=test] {Instructions exécutées si le test retourne Vrai};
   \node (incre) [process, below of=bloc] {Instruction d'incrémentation du compteur};
   \node (ins_after) [normal, below of=incre, yshift=-1cm] {Instructions après la structure itérative conditionnelle};
   \node (stop) [startstop, below of=ins_after] {Fin};

   % flèches
   \draw [arrow] (start) -- (ins_before);
   \draw [arrow] (ins_before) -- (init);
   \draw [arrow] (init) -- (test);
   \draw [arrow] (test) -- node[anchor=east] {Vrai} (bloc); 
   \draw [arrow] (bloc) -- (incre) ;
   \draw [arrow] (incre.east) -- ++(1,0) |- (test.east);
   \draw [arrow] (test.west) -- node[anchor=south] {Faux} ++(-1.5,0) |- ($ (ins_after.north) + (0,.5) $) -|  (ins_after.north);
   \draw [arrow] (ins_after) -- (stop);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I don't know how to create the break and continue node.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your is not MWE, so I construct my own. It is something between given picture and your attempt to wrote a code for it.

For shapes inside the "instruction block" I use a node in background layer, which fit all nodes ("Block d'instructions", "break;" "continue;" and "instructions", in front of it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,chains,decorations,positioning,fit,shapes}
    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 1 cm,
                > = stealth,
      start chain = going below,
every node/.style = {align=center},
 startstop/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, draw=red, fill=red!20,
                     minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, on chain},
  decision/.style = {draw=#1, fill=#1!20,
                     diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, on chain},
     block/.style = {draw=#1, fill=#1!20,
                     rectangle, rounded corners, 
                     text width=4cm, minimum height=1cm},
   process/.style = {block=#1, on chain},
    normal/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=white, 
                     text width=3cm, text=red, on chain},
     arrow/.style = {thick,->},
 arrow_red/.style = {thick,->,draw=red}
                    ]

   % noeuds
\node (start)       [startstop]     {Début};
\node (ins_before)  [process=gray]  {Instructions avant la structure 
                                     itérative conditionnelle};
\node (init)        [process=cyan]  {Instruction d'initialisation du compteur};
\node (test)        [decision=gray] {Test};
\node (block1)      [normal,draw=none,fill=none]  {Block d'instructions};
    \begin{scope}[node distance=0.5cm]
\node (break)       [normal]        {break;};
\node (continue)    [normal]        {continue;};
\node (block2)      [normal,draw=none,fill=none]  {instructions};
    \end{scope}
\node (iterative)   [process=gray]  {Instructions d'incremenatation};
\node (ins_after)   [process=gray]  {Instructions après la structure
                                     itérative conditionnelle};
\node (stop)        [startstop]     {Fin};
\scoped[on background layer]
    \node (instructions) [block=gray, inner xsep=0.5cm,
          fit=(block1) (break) (block2)]   {};

   % flèches
\draw [arrow]   (start)         edge    (ins_before)
                (ins_before)    edge    (init)
                (init)          edge    (test)
                (test) edge node[right] {Vrai} (instructions.north)
                (instructions)   --     (iterative);
\draw [arrow]   (test.west)  -- node[anchor=south] {Faux} ++(-1.5,0) 
                coordinate (auxiliary)    |- 
                ($(ins_after.north)+(0,0.5)$) -|  (ins_after);
\draw [arrow]   (iterative.east)  -- ++(1.5,0) |- (test);
\draw [arrow]   (ins_after) -- (stop);

\draw [arrow_red]   (break)     -- (auxiliary |- break);
\draw [arrow_red]   (continue.east)  -- ++ (1.5,0) 
                                     |- ($(instructions.south)!0.5!(iterative.north)$);
\end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{document}
```

Above code gives similar result as you show in your question.